# How can I get cmake to find cuDNN library in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, cmake, cudnn

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I want to to compile opencv-python with GPU support and gstreamer support. I have a GTX-1660 Ti GPU with Cuda-11.2 and cuDnn 8.9 installed.
When I try to configure the cmake command for this I get an error indicating that it is not able to find my cuDnn installation.

The error I get is this:

```
CMake Error at modules/dnn/CMakeLists.txt:56 (message):
  DNN: CUDA backend requires cuDNN.  Please resolve dependency or disable
  OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=OFF
```

The exact cmake command I used is this:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
-D WITH_CUDA=ON \
-D WITH_CUDNN=ON \
-D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON \
-D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=7.5 \
-D WITH_CUBLAS=1 \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
-D HAVE_opencv_python3=ON \
-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON ..
```

I checked with pytorch and tensorflow-gpu and these libraries are indicating that they are able to load cuda and cudnn.
Like so:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())  # This prints out True
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')) # This shows my GPU
```

and

```
import torch
print(torch.backends.cudnn.is_available()) # This prints out as True
```

Comment: CMake can look for specific version of cudnn, not that you installed. Or the lib binary file is located in folder that CMake doesn't check.

Comment: How can I resolve this?

Comment: just to be clear, do you want to disable `OPENCV_DNN_CUDA` or not?

Comment: No I do not want to disable this. I want to resolve the fact that it is not detecting my cuDNN.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide CUDNN library and CUDNN include installation paths to your cmake as shown below:

```
-D CUDNN_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.8.9.7 \
-D CUDNN_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include \
```

The above is for .deb installation

However if you installed CUDNN from .tar file and copied paths to lib and include folders to CUDA installation at /usr/local/cuda-11.8/ then provide the respective paths.